# PHP json decode doesn't work when string passed

Tags: php, json

My code is :

```
<?php
$text = "10";

$json  = json_decode($text);
$error = json_last_error();
var_dump(json_last_error() == JSON_ERROR_NONE);
var_dump($error);
```

This display bool(true) where it has to display error because $text is not json encoded value.

How to solve this?

Comment: perhaps json_encode($text), but what's the point

Comment: the point is it has to give error because string is not valid to decode. but it is giving int(0).

Comment: "10" is a valid json string, check  with http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: it give 0 that is bool(false)

Comment: BTW: Your question would be clearer if you renamed `$text` to `$json` (because that's what it's supposed to be) and `$json` to something generic like `$data`. The point is that after decoding JSON, you don't have JSON any more but only the data it represents. Anyhow, "10" is valid JSON representing an integer value, so your expectation that decoding it should fail is flawed.

Comment: you should use `is_object($decoded_json)`

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try to:

```
var_dump($json);
```

Instead of:

```
 var_dump($error);
```

Because `json_last_error()` returns the last error occurred.

But there is no error, so `var_dump($error);` displays `bool(true) int(0)`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use is_object($json) to check the string format.